# calculating percentages for repeat rate cohorts

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wrote a repeat rate query that gives me cohort repeat rate data in the following format:

```
cohort_join_day | repeat_day | repeat_users
11/15/16        |      0     | 10000
11/15/16        |      1     | 6000
11/15/16        |      2     | 3000
```

repeat_day 0 represents the total cohort size for that day

I'm trying to skip an excel step and  add a forth column with daily repeat rate percentages like so:

```
cohort_join_day | repeat_day | repeat_users | repeat_percentage
11/15/16        |      0     | 10000        | 100%
11/15/16        |      1     | 6000         |  60%
11/15/16        |      2     | 3000         |  30%
```

The calculation for this row should be pretty simple e.g.: 
day 1 cohort repeat rate on day 6 = (day 1 cohort repeat rate on day 6) / (day 1 cohort repeat rate on day 0)

(day 1 cohort repeat rate on day 0) represents the total size of the cohort

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Here's the daily repeat rate query I wrote:

```
    SELECT
  to_char(cohort_join_day, 'YYYY-MM-DD')            AS cohort_join_day,
  EXTRACT(DAY FROM (current_day - cohort_join_day)) AS repeat_day,
  COUNT(DISTINCT unique_id)                         AS repeat_users
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      auu.unique_id,
      date_trunc('day', auu.ds) AS current_day,
      date_trunc('day', fsb.ds) AS cohort_join_day
    FROM rust.a_unique_users AS auu
      JOIN mobile.first_seen_byos AS fsb
        ON fsb.unique_id = auu.unique_id
    WHERE
      auu.os_type = 'iphone_native_app'
      AND fsb.ds >= '2016-11-01'
  ) AS uniques_by_day
WHERE
  cohort_join_day <= current_day
GROUP BY
  cohort_join_day,
  repeat_day;
```

Comment: next time use `control-k` to format table as code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
    ,(repeat_users * 100.0) /
       MAX(CASE WHEN repeat_day = 0 THEN repeat_users END) OVER () as repeat_percentage
FROM
     Table
```

Conditional Aggregation and Window Functions makes this much easier

And if you are trying to do this calucation for every day then PARTITION the window function by cohor_join_day:

```
SELECT
    *
    ,(repeat_users * 100.0) /
       MAX(CASE WHEN repeat_day = 0 THEN repeat_users END) OVER (PARTITION BY cohort_join_day) as repeat_percentage
FROM
    Table
```

`MAX(column) OVER ()` would simply provide the `MAX` value in the `column` accross the entire data set.

`MAX(column) OVER (PARTITION BY column2)` will provide the `MAX` value in that column for the matching `column2` value.  You can think of `PARTITION BY` similar to `GROUP BY`.

replacing `column` with a *case expression* allows you to do *conditional aggregation*. So for example when you only want the `repeat_users when repeat_day = 0` a *case expression* saying that it will mean it will only return 1 value per partition and ignore the other values because they will be null.

So if you wanted to do the same thing in a straight query without the window function you would do something like this:

```
SELECT
    t.*
    ,(t.repeat_users * 100.0) / (SELECT t2.repeat_users
             FROM
                Table t2
             WHERE
                t.cohort_join_day = t2.cohort_join_day
                AND t2.repeat_day = 0)     as repeat_percentage
FROM
    Table t
```

And to show you how to do it with Juan Carlo's method when you have multiple days involved you could do it like so:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       cohort_join_day
       ,repeat_users
    FROM
       @Table
    WHERE
       repeat_day = 0
)

SELECT
    t.*
    ,(t.repeat_users * 100.0) / c.repeat_users as repeat_percentage
FROM
    Table t
    CROSS JOIN cte c
WHERE
    t.cohort_join_day = c.cohort_join_day
```

If you ever want a running total try something like

```
SUM(column) OVER (PARTITION BY column2 ORDER BY column3)
```

definitely get familiar with window functions they are life savers these days.

Comment: If you could be bothered to explain what the max / partition does here, that'd be amazing.

Comment: Really appreciate the explanation Matt! It appears this breaks down when the result data includes multiple cohort join days. See here: http://rextester.com/SNXN24181

Comment: @DanielRichter your welcome, I added a bit of test to explain and show you how to fix Juan Carlo's method to work for your multiple days

Comment: @DanielRichter yeah for the multiple days you need to use the one that has (PARTITION BY cohort_join_day).  It works http://rextester.com/UQR12583

Comment: Probably `MAX(repeat_users) over ..`  would be enough, If repeat **cant** growth.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yeah probably and I thought about it too but I didn't want to assume anything such as ability to pick up lapsed visitors that come back or something but I'd guess you are probably right in this and most cases

Answer (score 2):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/UEXE81984)**

```
WITH boo AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM foo     -- here go your query
), base as (
    SELECT "repeat_users"
    FROM boo 
    WHERE "repeat_day" = 0
)

SELECT boo.cohort_join_day,
       boo.repeat_day,
       boo.repeat_users,
       100* ((boo.repeat_users *  1.0) / base.repeat_users) as repeat_percentage
FROM boo
CROSS JOIN base
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: I have trouble getting this to work. The result set i'm getting back is not correct. See here for excerpt: http://pastebin.com/gJqbinTp. Maybe I set the query up incorrectly: http://pastebin.com/gCwB8xJK

Comment: Looks like things break down when the result set includes multiple cohort days. See here: http://rextester.com/OXHP63152